# How to share image from our app to another using intents and kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, intentfilter

I am trying to share a sample picture from my app to other person using Whatsapp/or other photo sharing app. But I don't know why it is not sharing. I don't know where in my code I am doing wrong. Please help me to solve the problem. I am using Intent to share the image.

My tried code files are as follows->

1. AndroidMenifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ImageShare"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.ImageShare">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="com.example.imageshare.MyFileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.imageshare.MyFileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_path" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

2. file_path.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

3. MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.imageshare

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.app.ShareCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider
import com.example.imageshare.ui.theme.ImageShareTheme
import java.io.File


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123 // You can use any integer value

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MainContent()
        }

        // Check if the permission is not granted
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            // Request the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            )
        } else {
            // Permission is already granted, proceed with the operation
            setContent {
                MainContent()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when (requestCode) {
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission granted, proceed with the operation
                    setContent {
                        MainContent()
                    }
                } else {
                    // Permission denied, handle accordingly
                    // You may show a message or take appropriate action
                }
            }
            // Handle other permissions if needed
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun MainContent() {
        // UI code with the Button and performFileOperation
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                performFileOperation()
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun performFileOperation() {
        // The code that involves interacting with external storage
        // For example, checking file existence and readability
        val imageName = "SolarSystem.jpg"
        val imageFile = File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), imageName)

        Log.d("MainActivity_Response", "Image exist? ${imageFile.exists()}")
        Log.d("MainActivity_Response", "Image can be read? ${imageFile.canRead()}")
        Log.d("MainActivity_Response", "Absolute path is ${imageFile.absolutePath}")
        Log.d("MainActivity_Response", "One more value is ${getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)}")

        // Create a Uri from the file using FileProvider
        val imageUri: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            applicationContext,
            "com.example.imageshare.MyFileProvider",
            imageFile
        )

        // UI code with the Button
        Button(
            onClick = {
//                Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
//                    type = "image/jpeg"
//                    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri)
//                    startActivity(this)
//                }
                ShareCompat.IntentBuilder(this)
                    .setType("image/jpeg")
                    .addStream(imageUri)
                    .setChooserTitle("Share image")
                    .setSubject("Shared image")
                    .startChooser()
            }

        ) {
            Text(text = "Send")
        }

    }
}
```

4. MyFileProvider.kt

```
package com.example.imageshare

import androidx.core.content.FileProvider

class MyFileProvider : FileProvider(R.xml.file_path) {
}
```

**Edited 1**
**What's in the edit?**

1. I am sharing some logs, that I had generated from MainActivity.Kt file.
   a. "2024-03-01 06:57:12.905  3628-3628  MainActivity_Response   com.example.imageshare               D  Image exist? false
   "
   b. "2024-03-01 06:57:12.905  3628-3628  MainActivity_Response   com.example.imageshare               D  Image can be read? false
   "
   c. "2024-03-01 06:57:12.905  3628-3628  MainActivity_Response   com.example.imageshare               D  Absolute path is /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.imageshare/files/Pictures/SolarSystem.jpg
   "
   d. "2024-03-01 06:57:12.907  3628-3628  MainActivity_Response   com.example.imageshare               D  One more value is /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.imageshare/files/Pictures
   "
2. I had used chatgpt too to resolve this issue. And it had asked to edit (which I had edited) some things ->
   a. Since, the first and second logs, as you can see, gives me false value. Therefore, it had suggested me to put the image in android file system using these two commands.
   "adb shell mkdir -p /sdcard/Android/data/com.example.imageshare/files/Pictures/
   "
   "adb push C:\Users\Pcc\Desktop\SolarSystem.jpg /sdcard/
   "
   "adb shell mv /sdcard/SolarSystem.jpg /sdcard/Android/data/com.example.imageshare/files/Pictures/
   "
   b. It has also given the edited code to manage permissions.(I had updated my code files here accordingly).
   c. And also some small twitches.

**Results I got after this modifications->**

1. For one to two times when after editing the code file accordingly, I started to get positive result. Even one to two times I successfully
   able to share the image in whatsapp and other platform too. The values for "Image Exist?" and "Image Can be found?" log was also started to returning true.
   But as you all know, "Curiosity kills the Cat.". After, when my app was perfectly working, since I had done many modifications in my code and I am very new to these concepts, I tried to understand the code by making small changes like commenting out some parts or maybe changing some approach. And then, after coming back to original correct code (maybe), here it goes again, MY APP AGAIN STARTED TO SHOW THE SAME RESULTS AS IT WAS SHOWING BEFORE. In whatsapp, it is showing"file format not supported.". And I had shared the logs with you also. I humbly request you to visit my edited code please.

**Edit - 2**
I tried another way to send the intent, by making resource uri of the image and then simply send it. And it was almost working but the issue arises was with the whatsapp app. I ckecked my code by doing work with this image using different apps like google Drive, Notes, Google search image they all are responding with correct image save . But when working with WhatsApp it is not sending "solarsystem.jpg" instead it is sending "null. bin" . I don't know what "null.bin" and why it is not getting the correct image. Please help me to resolve the issue for the whatsapp, because it is the app I want to use to allow the user to share the details for my main app.
Code is ->

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            UriBasicsTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    ) {
                        Button(onClick = {
                            val imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://$packageName/drawable/solarsystem")

                            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
                                type = "image/*"
                                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri)
                                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) // Add this line
                            }

                            if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                                startActivity(intent)
                            }
                        }) {
                            Text(text = "Click")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what happens instead? Where exactly it goes wrong?

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for responding to my question. The problem is when I tried to share the image from my app to the user using Intent it is not supporting. Although my app itself is neither crashing nor giving any runtime error. But, suppose for example when I Try to send the image through whatsapp , then the Whatsapp is giving me error as "The file format is not supported". I checked by changing the image but the response is same. I have edited my post. I request you to please visit it and tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: Use imageFile.exists() and imageFile.canRead() before using FileProvider.

Comment: Also share to other apps. Tell us.

Comment: @blackapps I tried "imageFile.exists() " and "imageFile.canRead()" just before I created imageUri variable and logged the response . Both are giving False as an output. That means, in my opinion, android can't get the image, right? But I have image in the directory "/C:/Users/Pcc/Desktop/SolarSystem.jpg" . I can;t understand then why android is not getting image. I am new to intent and data sharing concept or app development in general. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: @blackapps For other apps also , I am getting same response that they can't get the image.

Comment: That image is on your pc. On the C: partition. You Android app on your Android device has no access to files on the pc. So your path is wrong/unusable.

Comment: But i dont understand your  wrong path as File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is for your Android device and will never produce that path

Comment: Tell the value of imageFile.getAbsolutePath() as that is the path you use.

Comment: @blackapps First of all thanks of having patience and helping me. I had used chatgpt also to solve this problem, I had edited my code accordingly here. Please check it. For some time it was working fine. But again while sharing the image it is showing "file format is not supported" in whatsapp/or other app. I humbly request you to please check my edited code.

Comment: You did not tell full path. I asked for it.

Comment: It makes no sense to log the value of file.exists() and not act accordingly. You should use it like if (!file.exists()) return:

Comment: @blackapps I had mentioned the full path of the image in the logs I had shared in my edited question. The absolute path of my image is "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.imageshare/files/Pictures/SolarSystem.jpg". And also I can't how to use file.exist() value in my code. I humbly request , if you can provide me a code piece where I can use file.exist(). Thanks

Comment: if(!imageFile.exists()) return; you place just before requesting an uri from the file provider for it. Just as the canRead().

Comment: Now remove all the permission code as for that path you dont need any permisdion.

Comment: @blackapps when I used this "if(!imageFile.exist()) return" and inside this block I logged "Image doesn't exist" It is giving me output as image doesn't exist. Even though image is there in the android file system. But I can't understand why it can't get the image. I tried removing permissions too but it won't make any changes.

Comment: Remove your manifest from your post. Remove all imports. Remove all permission stuff. All irrelevant. Add the exists() and canRead() code.

Comment: @blackapps I made an edit in my question as "Edit-2", Please check it. It has almost solved my problem but I just need to figure out why it is not working for the WhatsApp.

Answer (score 0):

#### FileProvider

You need to extend `FileProvider` and set the `android:name` attribute in your app manifest to the FileProvider you created, like described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider).

```
package com.example.intentbasics

class MyFileProvider : FileProvider(R.xml.file_paths)
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <provider
            android:name="com.example.intentbasics.MyFileProvider "
```

Use `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder` instead of creating and starting an `Intent` by yourself.

```
    Button(onClick = {
        ShareCompat.IntentBuilder(context)
            .setType("image/jpeg")
            .addStream(imageUri)
            .setChooserTitle("Share image")
            .setSubject("Shared image")
            .startChooser()
    }) {
        Text(text = "Send")
    }
```

#### File location

You use external storage as your file location by using `external-path` in the `file_paths.xml` and `getExternalStorageDirectory()` when creating image URI. To get a better understanding of what external storage is please read `getExternalStorageDirectory()` method [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()). Usually it's going to be `/storage/emulated/0`, where your phone directories like Download, Music or Pictures are located.

#### Permisson

You don't check or request for file access permission which is required for accessing external files. Also, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is deprecated and you should add `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` permission. Read [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions) on media files permission changes in Android 13.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
```

For testing purposes you can grant relevant permission explicitly in the App info screen, but in a real app you'll have to request this permission.

Comment: @Jan_Itor Thanks for your response. but when I modified and tried to run it and send the image through whatsapp , The whatsapp is giving me response as "The file format is not supported" type response. The App is not crashing or is not giving any runtime error. I had edited my post with the changes you provided to me . I humbly request you to visit my code and tell me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: That means it can't find the image file. Log the directory returned by `getExternalStorageDirectory()` and upload the image file there on your phone/emulator. For emulator you can use Device explorer in the Android Studio. I've updated my answer regarding file location and permission. @Prakhar_Pathak

Comment: @Jan_Itor Thanks for helping me, I tried to solve the problem by myself also using documentation parts you shared and chatgpt. I had edited my code and some some logs also , please check them out. I hope that logs also will help me.